# I have encoding errors when build gradle module with autogenerated java classes from XSD

Tags: java, gradle, encoding, jaxb

I have gradle module for  generate java beans from XSD. I have folder with XSD files in resources and I write gradle task for generate.

```
configurations {
    jaxb // Only for generation purpose
}

dependencies {
    jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:2.2.11'
}

task generateSources() {

    doLast {
        def jaxbTargetDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources")

        if (!jaxbTargetDir.exists()) {
            jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
        }

        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath)

        ant.xjc(destdir: "${jaxbTargetDir}",
                encoding: 'UTF-8',
                removeOldOutput: 'yes',
                extension: 'true') {
            schema(dir: "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/schemas", includes: "**/*.xsd")
            arg(line: '-nv -disableXmlSecurity')
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn generateSources
```

My XSD files contains `cirilyc` text. I add `encoding` to `task`

```
encoding: 'UTF-8'
```

And when I start my `generateSources` task I get java beans with normal `cirilyc` text.

```
10:07:58: Executing task 'generateSources'...

:buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
:my-generator:generateSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
10:08:00: Task execution finished 'generateSources'.
```

Everything works cool. I open generated class and `cirilyc` text correctly displayed. But if I run `build task` on this module I get errors:

```
    10:09:19: Executing task 'build'...

    :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
    :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
    :buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
    :my-generator:generateSources
    path-to-my-project/InvalidMessageIdFormatException.java:10: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
     *                     Р?РґРµРЅС‚РёС„РёРєР°С‚РѕСЂ, РїСЂРёСЃРІРѕРµРЅРЅС‹Р№ СЃРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёСЋ РѕС‚РїСЂР°РІРёС‚РµР»РµРј, РЅРµ СЏРІР»СЏРµС‚СЃСЏ РєРѕСЂСЂРµРєС‚РЅС‹Рј СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРѕРІС‹Рј РїСЂРµРґСЃС‚Р°РІР»РµРЅРёРµРј UUID, РІР°СЂРёР°РЅС‚ 1 (СЃРј. RFC-4122).
                            ^
    path-to-my-project/MessageExchangePortType.java:53: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
         *                 Р”РѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅС‹Р№ РєРѕРЅС‚СЂРѕР»СЊ РґРѕСЃС‚СѓРїР° РІ Р?РЎ-РїРѕСЃС‚Р°РІС‰РёРєРµ РґР°РЅРЅС‹С… Р·Р°РїСЂРµС‰С‘РЅ.
                                                                                            ^
    path-to-my-project/\StaleMessageIdException.java:10: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
     *                     Р?РґРµРЅС‚РёС„РёРєР°С‚РѕСЂ (UUID), РїСЂРёСЃРІРѕРµРЅРЅС‹Р№ СЃРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёСЋ РѕС‚РїСЂР°РІРёС‚РµР»РµРј, СЃРѕРґРµСЂР¶РёС‚ СЃС‚Р°СЂС‹Р№ timestamp.
                            ^
    path-to-my-project/\AckTargetMessage.java:55: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
         *                 Р?РґРµРЅС‚РёС„РёРєР°С‚РѕСЂС‹ РїСЂРёСЃРІР°РёРІР°СЋС‚СЃСЏ СЃРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅСЏРј РѕС‚РїСЂР°РІРёС‚РµР»СЏРјРё.
```